# Installing Certificate on Websphere 8 for authentication

Tags: iis, websphere, certificate, client-certificates

I'm trying to add a .pfx certificate to Websphere8 server to establish a connection to an IIS server.
I tried to add the certificate to the deaultkeystore as a personal certificate and added the same as a signing certificate to the defaulttrustkeystore.
When ever I send a request through my application I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error.
I checked the communication b/w servers using Wireshark but there is no FINISHED message from either client or server.

So I wan't to know exact procedure to install a certificate on websphere server to get authenticated and thereby send the XML as a part of HTTPS Post request.

I contacted the web service provider, he said me that other users, or people who already implemented the client for this service, convert the pfx to .cer and send it along with the request. I also want to know how that is possible. I'm coding using Java 6.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the communication between the two is going to be? Is WAS initiating the HTTP call or is it receiving requests from IIS? I would perform some sanity checks to see that each of the WAS and IIS configuration are working well individually before trying to get them working together.

Comment: WAS initiates the request and then if authenticated receives response from the IIS.. basically two way communication needed.

Comment: In this case, you would need to only store the IIS certificates public key in your trust key store. IIS should be storing the public key of your WAS so that the handshake happens without any issue(s). You should not be storing the IIS's certificates to your keystore. It is worth reading this article even though it is not for WAS V8 as the fundamentals are still the same - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_birk/0612_birk.html